# Append html content in a div from remote end point using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, ajax

I have an external end point

`localhost:5000` which loads a simple html page with an image. A flask server is running there which serves html content.

I have another html file called `index.html` . In the `index.html,` I have a div called `movie-data` . I want to make a Ajax request `localhost:5000` and append the html content in the div `movie-data` of `index.html` .

`index.html` :-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function init() {

$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    url: "http://localhost:5000",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#movie-data").html($(data).append(data));
    }
});

init();

</script>

<div id="movie-data"></div>
```

It is showing error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
init();
```

Comment: NB: Think about what `$(data).append(data)` does.... It makes no sense.

Comment: if you use .html, it will replace old data, if u use append, it will append, check my answer

Comment: let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no closing tag of `function` was found

fix : -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function init() {

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    url: "http://localhost:5000",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#movie-data").append(data);
    }
  });
}

init();

</script>

<div id="movie-data"></div>
```

Comment: it is working. If I want to append data in iframe , do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Set a div in iframe with an id suppose framediv and then append data in it as framediv.append(data)